# Filesize is returned 0 on testing

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest, node.js-fs

I am reading file size of a file using `fs.statSync` on my application.

When testing, `fs.statSync` returns `size: 0`. And when actually running the application, it runs fine and return some size as it is supposed to.

Why could this be happening during testing?

Comment: How are you testing it?  Are you faking/mocking the file?  Is the file not found, since the tests are running in a different space?